# Let $f:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $0$. If $f(x)=f(x^2)$ for all $x \in (-1,1)$, prove that $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x \in (-1,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $0$. If $f(x)=f(x^2)$ for all $x \in (-1,1)$, prove that $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x \in (-1,1)$.

**Hint.** $c \in (-1,1)$. Consider the sequence $ \{ c^{2^n} \} $ in $(-1,1)$ converging to $0$. Use sequential criterion for continuity.

I have tried to go on with the hint but couldn't do much. I've set up the sequential definition for continuity at $0$ i.e. for every sequence $ \{ c^{2^n} \} $ in $(-1,1)$ converging to $0$ the sequence
$ \{ f(c^{2^n}) \} $ converges to $f(0)$. But from here I can't think of anything more.

I just need some help to nudge me to the right direction so that I can solve it myself.

Comment: Notice that $f(c) = f(c^2) = f(c^4) = \ldots$

Comment: The sequence $f(c^{2^n})$ is a constant sequence, by the given criteria. If it converges to $f(0)$, then that constant must be equal to $f(0)$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint..I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

What can you say about the values of $f(c^{2^n})$?

If $f(c)=\epsilon>0$, then what is $f(c^{2^n})$?

Now what does continuity mean for the sequence $\{f(c^{2^n})\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: Thanks for the hint ..I got it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:
Since $\ -1 < x <1$, $\ {x}^{n}$ tends to $\ 0$ as $\ n$ tends to infinity. Invoking the property given, we have,
$$\ f(x)=f({x}^{2})=f({x}^{4})=\lim_{n\to\infty} f({x}^{2n})=f(0)$$
The last equality is due to the fact that $\ f(x)$ is continuous at $\ x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, let's assume $c\in (-1,0]$. Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}c^{2^{n}}=0$. f is continuous at zero, so from Heine's definition of continuity, for each series $a_{n}$ such that $a_{n}\to 0, f(a_{n})=f(0)$. So, $f(c^{2^{n}})=f(0)$. By induction we can show that for every $n$, $f(c^{2^{n}})=f(c)$, and therefore $f(c)=f(0)$. c was chosen randomly, so for every $x\in (-1,0], f(x)=f(0)$. Same applies if $c\in [0,1)$ - you can check it if you want.